# Arduino ESP32-CAM Frame buffer clear

Tags: arduino, android-camera, esp32

I'm using ESP32-CAM for one of my project. The project is to capture image continuously 1 second duration and send to server. I can capture image and send it to server successfully.

But the problem is, it is not send current image frame. I think it sends image from its buffer which I want to clear. I mean I want to clear its frame buffer after capturing and image to get current image.

Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
const char* ssid = "ABC";
const char* password = "def";

//http://192.186.86.5:8787/Home/UploadFile
String serverName = "192.168.86.5";
//String serverName = "example.com";
String serverPath = "/Home/UploadFile";
const int serverPort = 8787;
WiFiClient client;

// CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

const int timerInterval = 10000;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;


int image_serial_no = 0;


void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); 
  Serial.begin(115200);

//Flash - pin 4

pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(4, LOW);



  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("ESP32-CAM IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;//PIXFORMAT_JPEG

  // init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;//FRAMESIZE_SVGA
    config.jpeg_quality = 6;  //0-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 10;//2  -- May be light
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;//FRAMESIZE_CIF
    config.jpeg_quality = 7;  //0-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 9;//1  -- May be light
  }

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  sendPhoto(); 
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= timerInterval) {
    sendPhoto();
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
}

String sendPhoto() {
  String getAll;
  String getBody;


  image_serial_no++;

//Flash - On
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);




  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  Serial.println("Connecting to server: " + serverName);

  if (client.connect(serverName.c_str(), serverPort)) {
    Serial.println("Connection successful!");    
    String head = "--Zitu\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\" "+String(image_serial_no)+".jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
    String tail = "\r\n--Zitu--\r\n";

    uint32_t imageLen = fb->len;
    uint32_t extraLen = head.length() + tail.length();
    uint32_t totalLen = imageLen + extraLen;

    client.println("POST " + serverPath + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + serverName);
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(totalLen));
    client.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Zitu");
    client.println();
    client.print(head);

    uint8_t *fbBuf = fb->buf;
    size_t fbLen = fb->len;
    for (size_t n=0; n<fbLen; n=n+1024) {
      if (n+1024 < fbLen) {
        client.write(fbBuf, 1024);
        fbBuf += 1024;
      }
      else if (fbLen%1024>0) {
        size_t remainder = fbLen%1024;
        client.write(fbBuf, remainder);
      }
    }   
    client.print(tail);

    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);

    int timoutTimer = 10000;
    long startTimer = millis();
    boolean state = false;

    while ((startTimer + timoutTimer) > millis()) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);      
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (getAll.length()==0) { state=true; }
          getAll = "";
        }
        else if (c != '\r') { getAll += String(c); }
        if (state==true) { getBody += String(c); }
        startTimer = millis();
      }
      if (getBody.length()>0) { break; }
    }
    Serial.println();
    client.stop();
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }
  else {
    getBody = "Connection to " + serverName +  " failed.";
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }





//Flash - Off
digitalWrite(4, LOW);



  return getBody;
}
```

Comment: Hi Maruf, we can't help you without your code. Please post the code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Edited & share my code.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I have found to avoid that lag/delay with the buffered data is to add:

```
config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST;
```

after "camera_config_t config;"

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clean solution for this but rather a workaround.

First, inside setup, set the frame buffer to 1 so only one frame will be buffered. It cannot be set to 0, so there always is one image too much.

```cpp
config.fb_count = 1;
```

Next, when reading the image, read it twice. This will clear the buffer and force the ESP32 to fill it up again with the fresh image.
In the `sendPhoto()` function, edit this block

```cpp
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
```

to this

```cpp
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb); // dispose the buffered image
  fb = NULL; // reset to capture errors
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); // get fresh image
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
```